# How to get changed content of inotify in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, inotifypropertychanged, inotify

I want to get the changed content of a textfile. Detecting file change using inotify in C++ works fine, but is there a way to get the changed content of a text file? The problem is that the event of inotify is consumed before the content is written so ifstream gives the previous output.

I am using inotify as follows (simplified):

```
fd = inotify_init();
wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, "myDir", IN_MODIFY);
while(1)
{
    i = 0;
    length = read( fd, buffer, BUF_LEN );
    while ( i < length ) {
        struct inotify_event *event = ( struct inotify_event * ) &buffer[ i ];
        if ( event->len && (event->mask & IN_MODIFY) && !(event->mask & IN_ISDIR)) {
            getNewContent();//-->if I use ifstream herre, I get the previous content
            cout<<event->name<<", WD"<<event->wd<<endl;
            i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
        }
    }
}

void getNewContent(){
    string temp;
    ifstream in("myDir/test.txt");
    while(getline(in, temp,';')){
        cout<<temp.c_str()<<endl;
    }
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: Do you keep the file open from before the change, or do you close and re-open the file after you get the notification?

Comment: I open for each event a new stream, see my code edit above.

Comment: Are you sure that it's the `test.txt` file that has been modified when you get the notification? It could be *any* file in the process' working directory, including the directory itself.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why are you mixing C++ with C? Why use `printf`?

Comment: as I manually edit the test.txt, I assume the event corresponds to the edit of test.txt. Regarding your second comment, thanks I will change that.

Comment: I recall that many text editors save to a temporary file and then rename it over the previous edition. Maybe you're getting the event corresponding to the save?

Comment: @SimonElliott Wouldn't that mean that a second event with the renaming? How could I, independently from where the file has been changed, get the changed content?

Comment: @user2212461: I think IN_MODIFY just tracks files being modified. This would be the temporary file saved by the editor. You need to track the move/rename, probably with IN_MOVE.

Comment: Your code (with added required declarations) works for me perfectly. Don't use an editor, you never know what it does, use `echo some silly text>> myDir/test.txt`.

Comment: ok, without the editor it works also fine for me now